# Why fs.writeFile is not working on GitHub?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have my own bot with an economy system. There is a roulette "!flip" the user can bet his coins, they are stored in (../coins.json) When i launch the bot from the computer (node ​​index.js) everything works fine, the bot itself changes the user's balance after a few seconds, but when I upload it to GitHub and run, the bot works fine at first, balance is saved, but after restarting everything disappears, it does not write to the coins.json file, how can I fix this?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
let coins = require("../coins.json");
const fs = require('fs');
const prefix = "!";

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  let prefix = "!";

  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

  let bal = parseInt(coins[message.author.id].coins); // Convert user's balance to number type

  if (bal < parseInt(args[0])) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, Not enough coins!`)

  if (random >= 70) {

  let win = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`${message.author}`)
  .addField(`You Won! `, `Number: ${random}`)
  .setColor("GREEN")
  message.channel.send(win)

    coins[message.author.id] = {
      coins: parseInt(coins[message.author.id].coins) + parseInt(args[0])
    }
    fs.writeFile("../coins.json", JSON.stringify(coins), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
  })
  };

  if (random < 70) {

    let lose = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${message.author}`)
    .addField(`You Lose! `, `Number: ${random}`)
    .setColor("#CB2E2E")
    message.channel.send(lose)

    coins[message.author.id] = {
      coins: parseInt(coins[message.author.id].coins) - parseInt(args[0])
    }
    fs.writeFile("../coins.json", JSON.stringify(coins), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
  })
  }
 };

module.exports.help = {
  name: "flip"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I can't comment yet, I'm asking you this way...
How are you running that project from Github? As GitHub is not a node.js runtime I think you'll need to deploy your app to something like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or a VPS.

If you're doing it with Github actions, you can't edit files with node.js filesystem. You could do it with an external database but I don't recommend to upload your database credentials to Github.

Comment: yes, i use heroku + GitHub, in GitHub i store my repositorie, the bot works well, 
charges and back the coins, but I want to export the database (coins.json), doesn't heroku already save it? Heroku can’t change files on GitHub even if the bot does it, as I understand it, but what i can do to save values ​​of user balances? @Puk

Comment: Try taking a look at this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku